# Grant File Permissions on Directory: Do they also apply to sub files?

Tags: nsis

I am trying to grant generic read, write and execute access to all users on my installation files. I am using the AccessControl plugin but my code isn't granting these permissions to all users, as a test I install the files as one user and try to delete a file as another user and I first get asked for admin privileges before I can delete it.

My code, maybe incorrectly grants permissions to the main installation folder. Does this also grant permissions to all the sub folders and files?

```
# resolves to C:/ProgramData/MyApplicationName
AccessControl::GrantOnFile "$APPDATA\MyApplicationName" "(BU)" "GenericRead + GenericWrite + GenericExecute"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add Delete access to the ACL:

```
AccessControl::GrantOnFile "$pluginsdir" "(BU)" "GenericRead + GenericWrite + GenericExecute + Delete"
```

but you are not supposed to give all users write access to shared areas! Applications are supposed to copy the data from the shared location to %AppData% if they need to modify the data. The ACL is inherited unless you use the /NOINHERIT switch.